# Проблемы с синхронизацией Gradle. :Ignoring Android API

Tags: android, gradle

Я пытаюсь подключить библиотеку [Moxy](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy):

```
compile 'com.arello-mobile:moxy:0.4.2'
compile 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-android:0.4.2'
apt 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:0.4.2'
```

Gradle выдает такую ошибку:

Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2 for debug

Полный build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '24.1.1'

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"

    ...
    compile 'com.arello-mobile:moxy:0.4.2'
    compile 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-android:0.4.2'
    apt 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:0.4.2'
    ...

}
```

Что делать?

Comment: У меня появляется такой же Warning, но приложение собирается и запускается. А у вас оно даже не запускается? Понимаю, что вопрос был задан давно, но может ещё актуально =)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема возникла после того, как обновился com.android.tools.build:gradle до версии 2.2.0. Раньше такого не было. Для хот-фикса необходимо исключить com.google.android из зависимостей:

```
compile ('com.arello-mobile:moxy:0.5.4'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android'
}
compile ('com.arello-mobile:moxy-android:0.5.4'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android'
}
apt 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:0.5.4'
```